# How can I make Reveal Modal work in Foundation 6?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am not sure why this basic reveal modal is not working... what am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

  <head>

    <title>index</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <meta name="description" />

    <meta name="author">

    <!-- Style Sheets -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

    <!-- HTML% shiv -->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>

        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

        <![endif]-->

  </head>


  <body>

    <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>

    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">

      <h2 id="modalTitle">Lorem Ipsum</h2>

      <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum lorem.</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</p>

      <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>

    </div>



    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/vendor/fastclick.js"></script>

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).foundation();

    </script>


  </body>

</html>
```

And here are the files:

[image: Files in folder]

Comment: Can you well formated your code please. Did you add the JS foundation script ?

Answer (score 1):

Your anchor should have the attribute `data-open="myModal"` or `data-toggle="myModal"`. Your close button should also be `data-close`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using the Foundation 5 reveal, it has changed for Foundation 6.

I have reformatted your reveal codeblock below adding the data-open to your open anchor and data-close to the close button and, the reveal block to have `class="reveal"`:

```
        <a href="#" data-open="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>

        <div id="myModal" class="reveal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
            <h2 id="modalTitle">Lorem Ipsum</h2>

            <a class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
        </div>
```

Zurb Foundation 6 Reveal: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html